# SQL Server 2005 Slow Query with Joins and Order By

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a slow query in SQL Server 2005. It has 3 inner joins (on tables with a few tens of thousand rows to one with a million rows), and an order by clause.

All the join keys are uuid columns, but there is only ever an index on one of the tables (each table has a primary key as a type uniqueidentifier, and another table will have a column acting as a foreign key with this same value to join on, but it has no index on it).

I assume adding an index on the acting-as-foreign-key columns will help this immensely.

What are my other options to get the most out of optimizing this query?

Note: my db seems to have a CPU bottleneck, would it seem reasonable to think that this query (which is run often) could cause it? The db is only about 2gb and I have 4gb ram, so I doubt there is much I/O issues. Will the order by eat up CPU?

Comment: I suggest you post the exact table definition, and all indexes, rather than a description of the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to index your join keys!  If you join on multiple fields, add covering indexes that cover all those fields (in the same order they are in the query).  That will probably take care of 90% of your performance issues.

It's possible to have a CPU bottleneck on a query like that since the server has to do table scans for all your joins.

Comment: the strange thing though is that even though I am missing the indexes, examining the query plan shows it only doing either clustered, or non-clustered index lookups. How could this be?

Comment: Are you looking at an actual or estimated execution plan?  Can you give us the info Remus asked for, table structure and indexes?  It's hard to diagnose based on incomplete information.

Comment: I can't post the actual table data, but what I described is essentially complete (with the exception of some columns on tables that are used in the order by). No other keys exist other than the uuid pk in each table (no foreign keys exist). But to answer to your question, this is an estimated execution plan.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan? It might help to see what it's doing. @JNK is right that indexing your join keys will likely help. Right now, I suspect that it's doing clustered index scans on the non-indexed tables (I assume those tables have PKs and people frequently use clustered indices to support their PKs), so that's probably why you're seeing the clustered index accesses. If the tables are particularly large, I would guess that their are hash joins involved; that will bump up your CPU. Also, if you have multiple CPUs, likely the scans are parallelized. The sorting also will bump up CPU

Comment: You are pretty much spot on with your assumptions (hash joins, parallelization, and clustered index scans). Given this, do you still think indexing the join keys would give substantial performance gains? Or would it be better worth my time to rewrite the query trying to use less joins

Comment: @Joda Maki - If you rewrite to use fewer joins you will still eventually be querying the same fields most likely, unless you are changing  your entire table structure.  Index the join keys and it should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

If your joins are inner joins you can create an indexed view. This will give you runtime performance as if there were no joins and no sorting at all. It does not get any faster than that (at the expense of disk space). If your joins are outer joins there is a workaround: Insert a dummy row that serves as a "null" kind of value and switch to inner joins.

As JNK pointed out, it is still important to index your foreign key columns. It is unlikely, though possible, that you can get away with not indexing them at all.

Comment: it won't help his performance to use a materialized view if the underlying tables aren't properly indexed.  The view still needs to be updated whenever data in the table changes, and that will be super slow without indexes on the right keys

Comment: The question was only about queries and my solution is 100% correct for this case. Yet, I have added a remark regarding the ordinary indices in order to cover the case that frequent data updates will be occuring. In any case, maybe my answer was not complete but always correct.